# Wide space from aisle to aisle/wide space of aisles?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, phrase-usage

[image]

Lets say you are describing a hypermarket wide space of aisle. And you say:

> "My hometown's hypermarket is convenient when you go in to buy their goods. One of the examples is the **wide space from aisle to aisle**, which gives people easier access amongst products."
>
> Or **''wide space of aisles''**

Is there something wrong about these bold letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [aisles](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/aisle) *are* the spaces between the shelving units.

> a long passage between rows of seats in a church, plane, theatre etc, or between rows of shelves in a shop

So, either you need to talk about the wide spacing between the shelves *or*, if you want to talk about the aisles, just say that they're wide:

> One of the examples is how wide the aisles are, which gives people...

This would be my preferred phrasing.

Comment: Am I wrong with that sentence construction?